# localhost doesn't find all files in Sites-Folder

Tags: apache, websites

I have a strange problem:

I installed XAMPP long time ago and created a folder with an index.php file in my sites folder. When i start XAMPP and go to the browser *localhost/~username* i can see the folder-structure.

> **I click on the folder i created some month ago, and safari shows me
>   the index.php file.**
>
> But now i create a new folder, with a new index-file in it, and
>   navigate to it, i'm getting an **404 Error**.
>
> **Both folders are in the same Directory: ~/Sites**

1. Open localhost/~username and i can see all folders in the ~/Sites - Folder
2. Clicking on the folder created long time ago: works
3. Clicking on the new folder created few seconds ago: Error 404

I think there is a problem in the apache-config file, but i do not understand why apache finds only the new file.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the permissions of the new folder? The content must be accessible by all users, otherwise Apache won't be able to read the content.

Comment: How did you configure XAMPP? Can you paste your Apache configuration?

Comment: @patrix: Permissions are the same for each folder.

Comment: @Gerry: Do you mean the httpd.conf - file? I don't understand: in the xampp-httpd.conf the document root is different than in the httpd.conf - file from /etc/apache2

Comment: Then you probably have the built-in Apache running as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i don't know why but i changed the Document-Root-Folder in the XAMPP-Config-File to match /username/Sites.

Now the other folders work, too.

I don't understand why one folder works with the old configuration, and newer ones don't.

To all with the same problem:

> The XAMP-Config-File must be the same document-root as the /etc/apache2 - config file on the mac

Strange thing, on my other Mac the Document-Paths are different but work.